# CSS dynamic classes with dynamic properties

Tags: css

I would like to generate a "numbered list" of classes with `z-index` value corresponding to the list number, i.e.:

```
.layer1 {
   z-index: 10;
}

.layer2 {
   z-index: 9;
}

.layer3 {
   z-index: 8;
}

...
```

Is there a way to do this in CSS such that I don't have to define all of the classes manually, but instead could use something like a for loop/pattern matching?

Comment: CSS has no such capability, but you could use a CSS preprocessor such as SASS, or pretty much any other generic programming language to generate the stylesheet you want.

Comment: If you find yourself in the need to define many z-index then your logic is wrong to start with. You have to try to find another way to do what you want without z-index. IMO, your question should focus and what you want to do instead

Comment: [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Ok, I have 8 `<canvas />` elements and want to stack them on top of each other in an order that may be different/reverse from the instantiation order.

Comment: You could use `position: absolute` to stack them and [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) to reverse their order.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do loops with pure `CSS`, but if you are using something like `SASS` then you can do like:

```
$total_layers_count: 10;

@for $i from $total_layers_count through 1 {
    .layer#{$i}
    {
        z-index:abs($i - $total_layers_count);
    }
}
```

**Transpiled**

```css
.layer10 {
  z-index: 0;
}

.layer9 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.layer8 {
  z-index: 2;
}

.layer7 {
  z-index: 3;
}

.layer6 {
  z-index: 4;
}

.layer5 {
  z-index: 5;
}

.layer4 {
  z-index: 6;
}

.layer3 {
  z-index: 7;
}

.layer2 {
  z-index: 8;
}

.layer1 {
  z-index: 9;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The question seems kind of vague, but if you need to use the z-index to stack the list elements then why not style them directly?

```
let container = document.getElementById("yourListContainerId")
let listElements = Array.from(container.children)

for (let index = 0; index < listElements.length; index++) {
    listElements[index].style.zIndex = listElements.length - index
}
```

Creating an Array from teh children property of the parent element will ensure that the elements don't get scrambled by using the `index` of the for loop to access the DOM elements from the `listElements` array. From there you assign the z-index to each element style starting at the top (`listElements.length`) and subtracting the `index` as the loop progresses. Let me know if this works, cheers!

edit: if for some reason you need to give a class to each element just add the following inside the loop:

```
listElements[index].classList.add(`layer${index}`)
```